# C# app to pass data to windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a windows service, which handles the updating of files from server on a daily basis.

I also have a simple C# app, which have the following options:

Install/Uninstall service
Start/Stop the service

And 2 textboxes with login button.

My idea is, on the login button click, if the service is running then stop it, pass login info in OnStart method, start it and let the service work (reestablish connection to server and so on).

My question is, is there an easy way to pass the login info from textboxes to OnStart method via it's args[], with a button click? I searched for solution, but they all suggest running service from a command line with parameters, and I need it to be operated from this app entirely.

I also found an article about named pipes, but I have troble understanding it. Also, the service need not any other parameters to pass, only those 2 strings from textboxes.

EDIT: will

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName", Environment.MachineName);
string[] args = new string[2];
args[0] = txtBox1.Text;
args[1] = txtBox2.Text;

sc.Start(args);
```

do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use string[0] etc but this would work:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName", Environment.MachineName);
string[] args = new string[2];
args[0] = txtBox1.Text;
args[1] = txtBox2.Text;

sc.Start(args);
```

You probably would need Administrator privileges to start the service this way.

I don't know the goal of the project but I'd also recommend checking out the service proerpties (running services.msc on a command prompt). If you view the properties, you can pass parameters using the Start Parameters field. Also you can run the service under any credentials you want using the Log On tab in case these may suit your needs.

Comment: Meh, I typed the edit hastly and wrote string instead of args, but I get the idea, thanks :) As for running properties and stuff, I can't really do that, the idea is the user just installs the service and doesn't have to do anything else, as they are not required to know anything about it.